# AWS RDS - does autovacuum return space to the OS, or just make it available for use in the same table?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

For context, I am working on archiving some data from large (65GB+) tables in a postgres DB on RDS. Following this, regular archiving will take place so the tables will remain small in the future.

I understand that deletes do not normally not free space to the operating system, because of the requirement for use of a 'VACUUM' process in postgres.

Having read the following articles, I'm not clear on whether the autovacuum process (which is on by default in AWS RDS) will free reclaimed space to the operating system (so available for use generally), or just make space available for reuse in the 'vacuumed' table.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/understanding-autovacuum-in-amazon-rds-for-postgresql-environments/

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Appendix.PostgreSQL.CommonDBATasks.Autovacuum.html

The Postgres documentation makes it clear that VACUUM FULL is much slower, requires `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` table locks and requires disk space for a temporary copy of the table (which we do not have). Because of this, I suspect that the autovacuum process will be equivalent to the 'non full' VACUUM operation in postgres, and will only free up space for use in the vacuumed table.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-vacuum.html

Can someone tell me if I am correct, or does autovacuum in fact free up space for general use?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: look into the pg_repack extension. Its available on RDS

Comment: Thank you VynlJunkie. No primary key / unique on tables in question so unfortunately not an option in this case.

Answer (score 2):

I can only answer for PostgreSQL, but it may apply if they didn't modify it too much.

Autovacuum (which runs `VACUUM` automatically) will typically *not* return free disk space to the operating system. The files that constitute the table won't shrink, but they will be come “emptier”, and future `INSERT`s and `UPDATE`s to the table can use that space.

The exception is *vacuum truncation*: if the last pages of the table have become empty and if PostgreSQL can get a brief `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock on the table, it will cut off these pages, which shrinks the file.